# Concatenating of two arrays results in null

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsfilemanager

I am trying to concat two directory listings into one array, I get the directory arrays to show the list of files in each separately (NSLog), but concatenating them together via addObjectsFromArray, results in (null):

```
NSString *path1 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop/Dir1/"];
NSString *path2 = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Desktop/Dir2/"];

NSArray *directoryList1 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path1 error:nil]
                                  pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

NSArray *directoryList2 = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path2 error:nil]
                                  pathsMatchingExtensions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"log", nil]];

NSLog(@"directoryList1 contains: %@", directoryList1);
NSLog(@"directoryList2 contains: %@", directoryList2);

NSMutableArray *directoryList;
[directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList1];
[directoryList addObjectsFromArray:directoryList2];

NSLog(@"directoryList contains: %@", directoryList);
```

Comment: You never create `directoryList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
NSMutableArray *directoryList;
```

defines a pointer to an array but doesn't create an instance. You should have:

```
NSMutableArray *directoryList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

so you have something to add the contents to.

Comment: Jep that's it thanks @Wain again! SO will let me accept it in 7 minutes, please be patient. I wonder why Clang doesn't show up any warnings on this, like uninstantiated object can't be modified or something...

Comment: It isn't a compile issue, not sure if a run of static analysis would raise anything. Technically there is no reason it couldn't be flagged as uninitialised when used.

Comment: Thanks @Wain it should really be included in static analysis, am on XCode 4 however, but I doubt that makes much difference in v5. Also I am thinking of renaming the question title to more appropriate fitting because of the answer, like "Concatenating of two arrays results in null"...